# Is there a way to delete Google app script project via their API?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking for a programmatic way to delete Google App Scripts project and I cannot seem to find one in the docs: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/manage-projects

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: There are some types for the project. What projects do you want to remove? Those are the project of [standalone script type](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone), [container-bound script type](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) and the script files in the project.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Since creating a script via the scripts API basically creates a .gs file in the Drive, you can use the Drive API to delete that file via it's ID