# Can you remove a Google Apps Script from a file using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-slides-api

I've got a container bound script which makes a copy of the slidedeck it's running in. What I'd like to do is either remove that script from the copy while it's being copied or after the copy is done since it may be shared externally - is that possible?

Comment: Have you done any research on your end already? Your question looks to be a duplicate of these existing posts [Is there a way to delete Google app script project via their API?] at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48680331/15384825 & [How can I delete container-bound scripts from multiple Google Documents or Sheets simultaneously without deleting the containers/files?] at https://stackoverflow.com/q/52919838

Comment: I did, yes. The first link you provided doesn't apply as that was regarding a standalone script project. I did see the second link you provided, but as the related response was 3 years old, I wanted to see if there were any changes since then.

Comment: I see. On my further research, it looks like there's no more possible simpler implementation (specially for bound scripts) other than the workaround mentioned from the second similar post at stackoverflow.com/q/52919838.